# Issue with Safari when playing audio with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, html5-audio

Why does this work in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but not in Safari (11.1)?
Trying to run it in Safari will result in the audio file being played one time only, no errors. Logging confirms that setInterval is still running.

```js
const sound = new Audio('sound.mp3');
const play = () => sound.play();

const handleClick = () => window.setInterval(play, 500);

const el = document.getElementById('play');
el.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='play'>Play</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why setInterval? change it to setTimeout if you want it to play after some time

Comment: What is the problem/error?

Comment: @karthick: the audio should be played multiple times in a row

Comment: @baao: (I added mored information in the description)
When running it in Safari the sound is played once, the setInterval keeps executing (e.g. console.logs are still being executed) but the audio is not being played correctly

Comment: I'm pretty sure safari blocks that, just like autoplay of a video.

Comment: @Dom why not use loop then?

Answer (score 1):

Safari 11 has included a new feature where an user interaction is required to play any media. Which means, the audio will play if you execute play like the below statement:

```
const handleClick = play;
```

Any event comes between click and play will not play the audio. Like setInterval in your case.

This feature is also introduced in Google Chrome 64.

[More info.](https://bitmovin.com/play-not-play-new-autoplay-policies-safari-11-chrome-64/)